# Are there any D&D novels with Demogorgon or other popular demon lords as antagonist?

Tags: novel, dungeons-and-dragons

There have been hundreds of D&D novels published over the years but I am having trouble finding any that have Demogorgon or other popular demon lords as antagonists.

Are there any? I do not care which milieu they take place in – Greyhawk, Forgotten Realms, or others.

Comment: Dragonlance has a villain series, do any of those count?

Comment: The only deity from the Monster Manual mentioned in that series was Tiamat, but she is a Lesser Power from the Nine Hells. Demons such as Demogorgon are from the 666 Layers of the Abyss.

Comment: ... or any book with Lord Soth in it.

Comment: @Mazura Lord Soth was a death knight not a demon lord.

Comment: I never saw Demogorgon being described as "popular" before, and get this vision of that gal in "Wicked" singing the song popular to him  Thank you for that insight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Gord the Rogue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gord_the_Rogue) novels by Gary Gygax: Sea of Death, Night Errant, City of Hawks, Come Endless Darkness, Dance of Demons - all involve many of the "Demons of Name" - Demogorgon, Grazz't, Juiblex, and literally dozens of others. Much of the action takes place in the Abyss, so demons abound.

Comment: I'd love to see more answers but I had no idea EGG's Gord the Rogue was so focused on demon lords. Thanks.